For two positive linear functional $\phi$ and $\psi$, if $\phi \leq \psi$, what is the relation between the two GNS representation?
The above question is singled out from M. Izumi's paper. The precise reference is pp 102 in Inclusions of  simple $C^*$-algebras in Crelle. In fact, I don't see why two positive functionals $\phi$ and $\psi$ satisfying $\phi \leq \psi$ induces $\pi_{\phi} \subset \pi_{\psi}$ where $\pi_{\phi}$ and $\pi_{\psi}$ are GNS representations from $\phi$ and $\psi$ respectively.
I am poor about the representation theory and quasi-equivalence between representations. Please explain details when you give me an answer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, precisely we fix a $C^*$-algebra $A$. Then we consider the GNS representation of $A$ with respect to a positive linear functional.

I don’t really want to write down all the details, since this is all pretty standard stuff. So feel free to treat this as a long comment or a hint if you so desire. The result you want is a direct consequence of (one version of) the noncommutative Radon-Nikodym Theorem: suppose $\phi \leq \psi$, let the GNS representation associated with $\psi$ be $(\pi_\psi, H_\psi, \xi_\psi)$, then there exists $0 \leq v \leq 1$, $v \in \pi_\psi(A)’$, s.t. $\phi(a) = \langle \pi_\psi(a)v\xi_\psi, \xi_\psi \rangle$ for all $a \in A$. A proof of this theorem may be found in, for example, Theorem 5.1.2 of Murphy’s “$C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory”. With this theorem, one easily verifies that $a\xi_\phi \mapsto av^{1/2}\xi_\psi$ induces an isometry from $H_\phi$ to $H_\psi$ and this isometry is the desired inclusion $\pi_\phi \subset \pi_\psi$.

Thanks, what I misunderstood was that the statement $\pi_{\phi}$ is contained in $\pi_{\psi}$ means that $\pi_{\phi}$ is a sub-representation of $\pi_{\psi}$. But you show that an intertwining operator $v$ manipulates the comparision between two representations. Your right answer is much appreciated.
